# What are the most popular Linux/Unix distributions for servers?

Tags: linux

I am considering trying out a few alternatives for CentOS. I have used CentOS since RH7.2 (2002?) and am an experienced user, but just looking to see how another OS would work out for me.

Currently I have to install a script on a server that requires perl 5.10 and I am most inclined to use a different distribution than CentOS for it, as I am not a fan of manual installation (see my other question) and am a little disappointed it doesn't come with CentOS.

I am wondering what the most popular distributions around are. I prefer an OS with a big user-base as it most often results in better and more support from the community. Also, I prefer CentOS over Fedora and Debian over Ubuntu, because I hold stability, speed and security in high regard.

Comment: Too vague....What is the requirement for the server/system you are hosting it on? What are the machine configurations and the application demands??

Comment: I would go for Debian myself, but the question is way too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major), there is a ranking of the major distributions.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular linux distribution nowadays is without any doubt Ubuntu, but it's not the most popular in the server enviroment, in the server enviroment maybe the most popular and utilized is RHEL (Red Hat and it's derived).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Anand, too vague. For a quick/simple answer, I would have to suggest that Ubuntu would have to be the most popular for desktop enviornments. Lots of online help/documentation.

As icefex mentioned, check Distrowatch